# Core Data merge error when deleting object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an entity `A` that `has many` `B`. `B` `belongs to` `A`.

When I load data from network, since I've read performing **upsert** operations with core data is either imposible or that's not the way it's supposed to be handled,  I went for the delete/insert way.

When I try to delete all `A`, I get an `Code=133020` `NSMergeConflict`. It makes sense because:  1) Where would those `B` entities that belongs to `A` end up, and 2) I **don't** want to delete `B` as in a `delete cascade`. I literally just want to update `A`.

That being said, it is clear delete/update is not the way to go (or at least not the way I'm doing it). So what's the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Right, delete update would require you to keep track of the to-many relationship objects as well and re-assign them to the new object. Because you also have to re-assign all other attributes, this seems to be much more work than just checking if the object already exists.

I am sure your network service has some unique attribute, such as an idNumber. You can use that to first do a lookup.

```
let filteredAObjects = allAObjects.filter { $0.idNumber == idNumberFromWebService }
let objectToUpdate = filteredAObjects.count == 0 ? 
  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityWithName("A",
                      inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! A :
  filteredAObjects.first
```